# JDO - Updating a One-to-one child

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have a Recipe. Each Recipe has an image. So my entity looks something like

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Recipe {
   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
   private Key key;
   @Persistent
   private MyImage myImage;
```

When I create the Recipe the first time, it works great, the image is
added as well and I can view it. However when I go and update it such
as

```
   PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
   Recipe r = pm.getObjectById(Recipe.class, recKey);
   try {
       r.setImage(newImage);
   } finally {
       pm.close();
   }
```

the new image is added to the data-store, but when I try and fetch it
from within the recipe, the recipe still points to the old image in my
data-store. Is this normal? How can I fix this?

**Here is the content of my jdoconfig.xml file**

```
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig">

    <persistence-manager-factory name="transactions-optional">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jdo.DatastoreJDOPersistenceManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="appengine"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalRead" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.NontransactionalWrite" value="true"/>
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.RetainValues" value="true"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns" value="true"/>
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem. Hopefully the bounty will help.

Comment: @Lumpy, unfortunately I fixed this by completely dumping owned relationships in favor of unowned relationships. I couldn't find any help online, and the reputation on here isn't helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the AppEngine implementation of JDO stores owned relationships in the form of parent keys. When you make myImageA a child of recipe1, appengine sets the parent of a MyImage entity to recipe1.

I'm not an expert on this, but I'm guessing that when you make myImageB a child of recipe1, appengine just sets the parent of *another* MyImage entity to recipe1. When it goes to retrieve `myImage`, it looks for an image with a parent of `recipe1`, and still finds `myImageA`, even though `myImageB` is still sitting there.

Again, I'm guessing.  I wish there was a "Submit Guess" option.

**TL;DR**: I'd try *deleting* `myImageA` explicitly before setting `myImageB`. That would break every other reference to `myImageA`, but if you're hoping to use it from other contexts an owned relationship is inappropriate anyway.

This kind of confusing mixup is why I dropped JDO & owned relationships altogether and learned to love Objectify. They also constrain your options for entity groups, which adds another dimension of fog.

Comment: Yes I also dropped JDO for app-engine, unfortunately. It was a standard layer that made my app-engine application work outside the google world. Does objectify work outside googlestore?

Comment: No, Objectify is 100% app-engine specific :(

Comment: This is pretty much the road I ended up taking.  If instead of creating a new object you get the object, update it, then store it, it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got to call `pm.makePersistent(r);` after setting the new image object to actually persist your change.

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `jdoconfig.xml`. Did you change anything in that file especially the values for `datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not required to do `pm.makePersistent(r);` because the Recipe is already persistent.
But in your code example you use non transactional read which means you can read instances from the datastore without a Transaction.
But if you want to do persistent modifications you need to use a Transaction.

```
   PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
   Transaction txn = pm.currentTransaction();
   txn.begin();
   Recipe r = pm.getObjectById(Recipe.class, recKey);
   try {
       r.setImage(newImage);
       txn.commit();
   } finally {
       pm.close();
   }
```

Comment: I've also tried with transactions. Same result. The image is added in the datastore, but the Recipe object still points to the first image.

Comment: What happens if you do a pm.refresh(r) ?

Comment: added that before `tx.commit();`. Still same results :(

Comment: I don't think you have to use transactions to persist changes to an object.  Guess: AppEngine just calls `put` on objects you've changed when you close the pm.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was getting the old object that needed to be updated then changing the object then storing it.  Adjusting your code gives us:

```
   PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
   Recipe r = pm.getObjectById(Recipe.class, recKey);
   MyImage newImage = r.getMyImage();
   newImage.setImage(newImageFile);
   try {
       r.setImage(newImage);
       pm.makePersistent(r);
   } finally {
       pm.close();
   }
```

This is basically what I did and it seems to work.

Comment: calling the makePersistent on already-persisted object shouldn't be necessary; closing the PersistenceManager should do the job of saving the changes.